# How come both var and let are throwing redeclaration errors?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was going through this snippet where they are saying that *let* keyword came in ES6 because *var* couldn't actually detect redeclarations or redefinitions of a variable. But when I run the code below I still get variable already declared error.

I ran this in the chrome console.

```
var x = 10;
var x = 20;
```

Same as

```
let x = 10;
let x = 20;
```

Comment: *"I was going through this snippet where they are saying that let keyword came in ES6 because var couldn't actually detect redeclarations or redefinitions of a variable"* what snippet? because.... that's not why let exists..

Comment: I tried myself in the Chrome console and it doesn't complain...

Comment: Were you perhaps running `var x = 10;` _after_ `let x = 10;` from an earlier test? `var x = 10; var x = 20;` isn't an issue, but it would be if `x` already existed from an earlier `let x =`.